# how to add rule for time in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, rules

I want to add a rule in laravel that is based on time type string. User will send time of song like **mm:ss** sometime it will nullable and sometime it will send time of song 2:50. I have added below code but i am unable to add time rule.

```
    $data = request(['songTime']);
$rules = [            
            'songTime' => 'string|nullable|MM:SS'
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);
        if ($validator->fails() ) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Invalid Request',
                'error' => $validator->messages()
            ], 400);
        }
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#using-rule-objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways I would suggest, the first is to use Laravel's [regex](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-regex) rule.

```
$rules = [            
  'songTime' => ['string', 'nullable', 'regex:/\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}/']
];
```

You'd need to tinker with the regex a little, this will accept any pattern of one or two digits, a colon, and digits. So something like 2:99 will be erroneously accepted.

The other alternative is to write a [custom rule](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#custom-validation-rules). The example here is using a closure, but I'd highly recommend extracting it into its own class.

```
$rules = [
    'songTime' => [
        'string',
        'nullable',
        static function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            [$min, $sec] = explode(':', $value);

            if (ctype_digit($min) === false || ctype_digit($sec) === false || $sec > 59) {
                $fail($attribute . ' is invalid.');
            }
        },
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use date_format rule validation like H:i:s or i:s, And also you can use form validation request that will make your code smaller into controller file.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ValidateSongTimeRequest extends FormRequest {

 /**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize() {
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules() {
    return [
         'songTime' => 'required|date_format:H:i:s'
    ];
}
}
```

and in a controller file, you can use like this,

```
public function validateTime(ValidateSongTimeRequest $request) {
    $inputs = $request->all();
    try {
        
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        Log::error($exception);
    }
 throw new Exception('Error occured'.$exception->getMessage());
}
```